# Python 2.7 reading template and returning new file with substitutions

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variable-declaration

I am currently loading my data into a variable (seen below as 'data') and then reading my template file and replacing %s with variables contained in 'data'. Here is my page reading, substitution, writing then displaying the new page on local server code:

```
def main
    contents = makePage('varibletest.html', (data['Address'], data['Admin'], data['City'], data['ContractNo'], data['DealStatus'], data['Dealer'], data['Finance'], data['FinanceNumber'], data['First'], data['Last'], data['Message'], data['Notes'], data['Result'], data['SoldDate'], data['State'], data['Zip']))   # process input into a page
    browseLocal(contents, 'Z:/xampp/htdocs/', 'SmartFormTest{}.php'.format((data['ContractNo']))) # display page

def fileToStr(fileName): 
    """Return a string containing the contents of the named file."""
    fin = open(fileName); 
    contents = fin.read();  
    fin.close() 
    return contents

def makePage(templateFileName, substitutions):
 """Returns a string with substitutions into a format string taken
 from the named file.  The single parameter substitutions must be in
 a format usable in the format operation: a single data item, a
 dictionary, or an explicit tuple."""

pageTemplate = fileToStr(templateFileName)
return  pageTemplate % substitutions

def strToFile(text, savefile):
    """Write a file with the given name and the given text."""
    output = file(savefile,"w")
    output.write(text)
    output.close()

def browseLocal(webpageText, path, filename):
    """Start your webbrowser on a local file containing the text."""
    savefile = path + filename
    strToFile(webpageText, savefile)
    import webbrowser
    b = webbrowser
    b.open('192.168.1.254:1337/' + filename)

main()
```

Here is my template file (included is some silliness to demonstrate I have tried quite a few things to get this working):

```
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s.format(Address)
%s.format(data['Address'])
%s[2]
%s(2)
%s{2]
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
```

When the new page is opened the variables are all there in sequential order. I need the ability to insert, say, address in multiple places.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT --

Here's my new code with solution:

```
def main()
    fin = open('DotFormatTemplate.html')
    contents = fin.read();
    output = contents.format(**data)
    print output

main()
```

Template file:

```
I live at
Address: {Address}
```

Hope this makes someones life easier as it did mine!

Comment: Your way of using templates is a bit exotic. Try using `jinja2` tutorial to get some feeling how it is done usually.

Comment: Alright, so, by changing the template to have "%s"%(Address) I get the following error: 'line 34, in makePage
    return  pageTemplate % substitutions
TypeError: format requires a mapping' Which I believe is progress!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Simple templates using `string.format`

Typical way of rendering simple template by means of `string.format` method:

```
data = {"Address": "Home sweet home", "Admin": "James Bond", "City": "London"}

template = """
I live at
Address: {Address}
in City of: {City}
and my admin is: {Admin}
"""
print template.format(**data)
```

what prints:

```
I live at
Address: Home sweet home
in City of: London
and my admin is: James Bond
```

The `**data` is needed to pass all `data` keywords and related values to the function.

## Using Jinja2 for loopy templates

`string.format` is great in that it is part of Python standard library. However, as soon as you come to more complex data structure including lists and other iterables, `string.format` comes short or requires building output part by part, what makes soon your template broken to too many parts.

There are many other templating libraries, `jinja2` being my favourite one:

```
$ pip install jinja2
```

Then we can play this way:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> jdata = {'Name': 'Jan', 'Hobbies': ['Python', 'collecting principles', 'DATEX II']}   
>>> templstr = """
... My name is {{ Name }} and my Hobbies are:
... 
... {% for hobby in Hobbies %}
... - {{ hobby }}
... {% endfor %}
... """
>>> templ = Template(templstr)
>>> print templ.render(jdata)
My name is Jan and my Hobbies are:


- Python

- collecting principles

- DATEX II
```

With `jinja2` there is no need to call `templ.render(**jdata)`, but such call would also work.

## Conclusions

Samples above shall give you initial idea, what can be done with templates and how they can be used.

In both cases there are many more functionalities provided by given solutions, just read doc and enjoy it.

Comment: Great thanks! I will edit my post to show what I did.